# How do you add and remove an information template by clicking on an SVG element in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

So, I am thinking something along the lines of a tool tip or a pop-up, except with much more information in it, and I also want every information box to be in the same location on the page. Overall, I just want to be about to click on an SVG (that represents some data element), and on a click event, trigger and information box to pop up in front of it; maybe even give it it's own close function if it covers the SVG. I know I have seen this many times before, but the exact name is escaping me at the moment.

Right now, I have a circle:

```
    node.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", sankey.nodeWidth()/2)
        .attr("cy", function(d){return d.dy/2;})
        .attr("r",function(d){return Math.sqrt(d.dy);})
        .style("fill", function(d){return d.color = color(d.name.replace(/ .*/,""));})
        .style("stroke", function(d){return d3.rgb(d.color).darker(1);})
        .style("stroke-width",5)
        .on("mouseover", tip.show)
        .on("mouseout", tip.hide)
        .on("click", changeColor(function(d){return d.color;}))
        .append("title")
```

I'm hoping to write something like:

```
    .on("click",function(d){/*Create a rect element*/})
    .append("text", "This element represents the "+d.name+" element and will weigh approximately "+d.weight+"lbs.")
    .attr("cx", 50)
    .attr("cy", 50)
    .on("click_exit?" function(d){this.remove();})
```

I am not certain how to approach this, but I just want a text box to display on click and have an exit button (or some closing method) to close it. Can I add something like the above code to my previous code, or must I create an entire new svg element completely disjoint from it?

Answer (score 0):

I've done things similar to this before, i've found that SVG can be a real pain when not doing actual d3 graphical stuff. I would work with html in this case.

What i did was create an html element with the desired template, absolutely position it where i wanted, and then set `display:none` or `opacity:0`.

Then for your onClick function

```
.on("click",function(d){
    d3.select('.my-info-box p')
        .append(d)
        .style('display','block')
})
```

This is the bare bones functionality. The takeaway here is to use html and not svg. To close it you can position a `&times;` in the top right/left of the box, and then onClick, close the info box.